# Is it possible to save Safari settings somehow?

Tags: macos, safari

I want to be able to save things like Safari's Toolbar configuration, etc. (not just bookmarks and the like).

Is there a way to back up these configuration and layout choices?

Comment: You might want to look at the files in the folder `~/Library/Safari` and the multitude of com.apple.safari.xxx.plist files in `~/Library/Preferences`. YMMV as there may be other files I can't find. (Note: ~/ is shorthand for `/Users/_your_user_name_`).

Comment: Thank you, if you provide this as a solution I'll mark is solved

Comment: I've never done this, so I don't know if this is a solution! Have you tried backing up all these files, deleting them, running Safari to see if the settings have been reset, then restoring the files to see if the settings are restored? If it does work, then I'll make my comment into an answer and you can mark it as solved.